# AWS glue error with apply_mapping method of DynamicFrame (IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type name string)

Tags: aws-glue

I have a table in catalog that contains struct and array columns. I want to move this data and query it with redshift. In doing so, I want to change the struct and array columns to string. However this is not working.

My first approach was to directly try the conversion:

```
new_df = df.apply_mapping(
    mappings=[

        ("col1","struct","col1"," string"),
        ("col2","struct","col2"," string"),
        ("col3","array","col3"," String"),
        ("col4","array","col4", "string"),
       
    ],
)
```

However it didn't work. The exception I got was **IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type name  string**.

In my second approach, I tried to convert the DynamicFrame to a spark frame using toDF and used withColumn to cast all arrays and structs to json. Then I converted them back to a DynamicFrame using fromDF (call it *converted_df*)
and used similar approach as above

```
new_df = converted_df.apply_mapping(
    mappings=[

        ("col1","string","col1"," string"),
        ("col2","struct","col2"," string"),
        ("col3","array","col3"," String"),
        ("col4","array","col4", "string"),
       
    ],
)
```

But it still gives the same error.

What am I doing wrong? How can I convert an array or struct to a string?

Thanks in advance.